# Fire up a web browser for a folder?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, webserver

Is there an easy way to fire up a web browser for a folder?

eg.

I am in a folder that contains a website (index.html and other files) and I want to browse the site through a browser. Is there a gem that I just launch to make this folder browsable?

In this way I don't have to install nginx just for a specific folder. And when you install nginx you have to bother with configuration files and so on.

Kinda how Rails does it with:

```
rails server
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is...  Throw the following in a file called webserver:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'webrick'
include WEBrick

server = HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3000, :DocumentRoot => Dir::pwd)

trap("INT"){ server.shutdown }
server.start
```

Then, perform the following (This assumes Mac OSX):

```
$ sudo chmod 755 webserver
$ sudo chown root:wheel webserver
$ sudo cp webserver /usr/local/bin/webserver (or somewhere in your path)
```

Now, just run `webserver` from the directory you want to use as the document root.  A webserver will now be running on localhost:3000.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

I just remembered after reading a post on Phusion Passenger 3.0 progress that there will be a [passenger lite](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/07/01/the-road-to-passenger-3-technology-preview-3-closing-the-gap-between-development-and-production-rethinking-the-word-easy/) option...

Comment: I see a lot of these solutions with Webrick. Is this possible with Mongrel and Thin too? Why do they all use Webrick?

Comment: I'm pretty certain it is just as easy to do w/ mongrel or thin.  I believe that most examples use WEBrick because it is included with the Ruby distribution.  Honestly, for simple tasks, WEBrick is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I've found is this little Python one-liner:

2.x:
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

3.x:
`python -m http.server 8080`

Unless you want to execute Ruby dynamically, of course. But that wasn't explicit in your question. Only static HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The webbrick example works great, thanks to Brian. However, I just wanted to follow up on his update.

Assuming you have a [working ruby and rubygems](http://railsinstaller.org) installed:

```
gem install passenger
```

put all files in a subdirectory called `public`

example project dir:

```
.
├── any
│   ├── old crap
│   └── that will not be on the website
└── public
    ├── favicon.ico
    ├── images
    │   ├── ajax-loader-large.gif
    │   ├── bg.jpg
    │   ├── bg_home.jpg
    │   ├── bg_nav.gif
    ├── index.html
    ├── javascripts
    │   ├── jquery.liveSearch.js
    ├── robots.txt
    └── stylesheets
        ├── all.css
```

Then run `passenger start`

The first time it will install a bunch of things (including nginx, but you won't have to worry about configuring it), but it should work faster after that.

Answer (score 0):

And, if you have PHP >= 5.4.0, you can:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

That's pretty easy!

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php